# What is the best way to build Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, etl

I want to make a website that gives a visualization of football game statistics.
Functionality: The user checks a list of games. Selects game to see details. Can select a particular player. If there is no game he/she is interested in, the user uploads a datafile of the game and adds it to the main list of games.

I have a script that cleans data and gives me DataFrame with columns:

```
['Shots', 'SCA',  'Touches',  'Pass',  'Carries',  'Press',  'Tackled',  'Interceptions',  'Blocks']
```

if I do the Django model is it ok if I simply do model with these columns, or do I need to do a proper database with separate tables like:
[image]

Is my UML is ok or do I need to fix something?
here is link to my UML https://drawsql.app/xml-team/diagrams/football-game-stats

Comment: The question is not about how to create tables. I do not know how to build/create/write Models. I gave an example of possible Models in the pic above. Are those relationships is correct? How would you build models to show Football game statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually create tables and relations in your database, Django can take care of that for you.

It has been explained in detail [here](https://www.webforefront.com/django/setuprelationshipsdjangomodels.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am aware that Django creates bd and relations. I can understand how to write models. If you are creating a Football statistics app how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following these simple steps for building Django Model. I always did by following these steps.

1. Create Django Application
2. Add the Posts Model
3. Update Settings
4. Make Migrations
5. Verify Database Schema